# SQL select items from one table with conditions from another

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 Tables:

```
Accounts(ID, Name, Adress, Type)

Holidays(Name, StartDate, EndDate)
```

And the Type column from Accounts is a  `SET("Manager","Director","Administrator")` for example.

The Name Column for both colums are relationed. When someone creates a holiday, the Name from table Holidays will be his name from the account that is logged in.

And i want to know if it's possible to make a SQL statement where i can take all of table 2 which the the table1.type need to be "Director" and the Table1.name needs to be on holidays.

Comment: what do you use - mysql or sql ?

Comment: mysql , and i will use PHP

Comment: *and the Table1.name needs to be on holidays* - now, date range?

Comment: Date range don't matter, just want to take all the info from table 2 that fits on that 2 conditions from table 1

Comment: You should use the `ID` in `Holiday`.  That is why there is an `ID` -- so you don't have to use `Name` to connect the two tables.

Comment: i actually have an ID on holiday,  but i think i will not need to use in this

Comment: @Andre GordonLinoff says that it's better to link tables by field in Holidays table for example account_id equal to ID from Accounts table, as far as I understood

Comment: Hmm,  Thanks,  i will use like that then to because it can have same names and it's bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Accounts as a, Holidays as h WHERE a.Name = h.Name AND a.Type = 'Director'
```

This should get you all the entries you want. It's important to link `a.Name` to `h.Name` to ensure that you get the right combination.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will make the trick. You don't need to check for the name in Holidays because when we are making the left join we say take the records where the name is equal on both tables. If it is not in holidays you are not going to get any records.

```
select Accounts.ID,Accounts.Name,Accounts.Adress,Accounts.Type,Holidays.Name,Holidays.StartDate,Holidays.EndDate from Accounts left join Holidays on Accounts.Name=Holidays.Name where Accounts.Type = "Director";
```

Comment: Hey mate , it gave me blank rows

Comment: I just change the code. Are you sure that the "Director" has start his holidays?